# Evaluation order of callee and arguments?

Tags: java

I just wrote a method looks like this.

```java
public static <T, R> R requireNonNull(final T obj, final Function<? super T, ? extends R> function) {
    return Objects.requireNonNull(function, "function is null")
            .apply(Objects.requireNonNull(obj, "obj is null"));
}
```

Which one of following parts get evaluated first?

- `Objects.requireNonNull(function, "function is null")`
- `Objects.requireNonNull(obj, "obj is null")`

Comment: `requireNonNull(function, "function is null")`. It wouldn't go to the chained method call before successfully executing the first one.

Comment: @ernest_k Can you please make your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? Thank you.

Comment: There's a good answer, with references to the spec on the linked question.